# How to insert data into database using Web API 2 in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have below code in Controller

```
    // POST api/PersonalDetails
    [ResponseType(typeof(PersonalDetails))]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostPersonalDetails(PersonalDetails personaldetails)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.PersonalDetails.Add(personaldetails);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = personaldetails.AutoId }, personaldetails);
    }
```

and below code in view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var PersonalDetails = {
        "FirstName": $("#FirstName").val(),
        "LastName": $("#LastName").val(),
        "Age": $("#Age").val(),
        "Active": $("#Active").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:28206/api/PersonalDetails/PostPersonalDetails',
        data: JSON.stringify(PersonalDetails),
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert(status);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, when I am clicking on the button that fires up btnAdd click method. The controller PostPersonalDetails method is executing but personaldetails object is null. I am not able to retrieve values of the form.

How to get values of the PersonalDetails object formed in the click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved this problem and have written an article to help others.

[Inserting record into database using ASP.NET MVC with Web API](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2888/inserting-record-into-database-using-aspnet-mvc-with-web-api)

Hope this will be helpful for others looking for similar kind of problem.

Thanks